# AJAX sending data to Node.js server

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, http

I'm trying to send data with AJAX to a Node.js server but keep bumping into the same issue, the reception.

Here is the client-side JavaScript / AJAX code :

```
    var objects = [
        function() { return new XMLHttpRequest() },
        function() { return new ActiveXObject("MSxml2.XMLHHTP") },
        function() { return new ActiveXObject("MSxml3.XMLHHTP") },
        function() { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") }
    ];
    function XHRobject() {
        var xhr = false;
        for(var i=0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            try {
                xhr = objects[i]();
            }
            catch(e) {
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
        return xhr;
    }
    var xhr = XHRobject();
    xhr.open("POST", "127.0.0.1:8080", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/csv");
    xhr.send(myText);
    console.log(myText);
```

For some reason the basic HTTP server you can get on [http://nodejs.org/api/http.html](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html%20nodejs.org) was causing `ECONNREFUSED` errors (even with sudo and port 8080) so I tried with this simple code :

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    console.log('res: ' + JSON.stringify(res.body));
}).listen(8080, null)
```

But it keeps printing `res: undefined`.

On the other hand, the `AJAX` `POST` doesn't seem to trigger any errors in the console.

So my question if the following :

- How can I have a simple but solid node.js server that can retrieve
  text that was send by an `AJAX` `POST` request ?

Thank you in advance !

Edit : The testing is done on `127.0.0.1` (localhost).

EDIT2: This is the updated Node.js code :

```
var http = require('http');

    var http = require('http');
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      res.end();
      req.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      })
    }).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at example on http://nodejs.org home page.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

1. Node.js request object have not request body as plain text. It need to be handled by chunks from `data` [event](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_data).
2. You need to end request with res.end to send response to client.

**Update:**

This code should work fine:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var body = '';
  req.on('data', function(chunk) {
    body += chunk.toString('utf8');
  });
  req.on('end', function() {
    console.log(body);
    res.end();    
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: I don't want to send anything back, just receive what the client (AJAX) did send. The AJAX isn't a GET request but a POST.

Comment: Request must be completed in all cases. Client will waits for request end. If you don't need to send data back, just complete request with res.end(); without parameters.

Comment: Ok, so I tested your updated code, but it's still printing `undefined`. My node.js version is `v0.8.2` if that has any importance at all.

Comment: Sorry, my fail. Node.js request have no plain request body by default.  It need to be handled by chunks from `data` event. Check update now.

Comment: Hum, so strange, the code you just added works, like no errors, but it only prints new lines for some reason.

Comment: I have tried to just send static text with AJAX but node.js keep printing new lines ... ;X

Comment: I just checked this code and it works fine for me, but i sended request with another server side script. Looks like some error in your AJAX clinet code now.

Comment: Yes, it seems like it. It's strange though because I'm not getting any errors in the JavaScript console but I will look into it.

Comment: In your client code, change content type from `text/csv` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Add `http://` before `127.0.0.1:8080`

Comment: YES ! It wooorks ! Oh, I'm so happy right now ! ^^ Thank you so much with the help !! At first I had `text/csv` because the JavaScript string I was sending is formated in csv but apparently your are not supposed to do that. Good to know !